# How to get values from a config file

Tags: c, configuration, strtok

I have the following Config.cfg

```
[DD]
user=**
password=***
database=***
IPServidor=****
port=***

[Controller]
Control1=8
Temp=5
Hum=7
Link=8
Volt=9

[Controller]
Control2=10
Temp=5
Hum=7
Link=8
Volt=9
```

I would like to read the values of the controllers only and print them to the screen like

```
Controller_8: 5,7,8,9
```

I do not want to use libconfig or glib because I have problem with undefined functions. I did the installation, I have the headers but I do not know why it does not work. So I want another solution. My first thought is with the usage of strchr to find the lines which I want (to ignore [DD] table in my case) and with the usage of strtok to get only the values of temp,hum,link,volt

```
 char buffer1[100];
 FILE *f = fopen("/home/pi/Desktop/Config.cfg","r");
 while(fgets(buffer1, sizeof(buffer1), f))
{
    printf("%s",buffer1);
    char *pos1 = strchr(buffer1,'Controller');
    if (pos1)
    {

    item = strtok (buffer1,"Control");
    printf("Results: %s\n", buffer1);
    }
}
```

The above code is not correct. Is just a thought. Is there any better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try parsing ini files, use some existing library.

Ini file parsing is included in a number of "frameworks", for instance in [Gtk+](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.30/glib-Key-value-file-parser.html) or on [Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). If you can't access those, you can still use some standalone library, for instance: http://ndevilla.free.fr/iniparser/